# Show documents category on a page based on term sets

Tags: document-library, search, managed-metadata, term-store, refinement-panel

I want document library, having a metadata column associated to a term set.

Now on a page, I want to show different icons(category of the document) based on Terms.

- On click of parent category icon, it should redirect to a page having category icons under that parent category(child terms).
- On click of a child category, it should redirect to a page having documents of that specific category only.

How do I achieve it? Also, how to automate if I have to create similar multiple libraries and different term sets.

Comment: Have you tried `Metadata navigation settings` under document library settings? This gives option to filter documents based on a term. It doesn't give the icons or exactly the way you require but helps in filtering via terms.

Comment: Thabk you ahmad for the reply. I am aware of it and we can achieve it by refinement webpart or content query webpart. I am looking for custom icon  and automation for multiple libraries

Comment: Your requirements across multiple lists and libraries can be achieved by a custom solution. Let me know if custom solution is feasible in your case and I will post its design